# Create a firebase function to set negative server timestamp in database but keeping NaN

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am not familiar with javascript but I would like to create a firebase function that will set a negative server timestamp on a ref but I keep getting the same error:

> Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property

Here's my code:

```
exports.makeNegativeTimestamp = functions.database.ref('/items/{itemID}/negative_created_timestamp')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const timestampCurrent = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    const now = Date.now().valueOf();
    var negativeTimestampCurrent = (now * -1);
    return snapshot.ref.set(negativeTimestampCurrent);
});
```

I tried using both `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to set value and `Date.now().valueOf()` but both lead to that same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not a value that you can read. It is a so-called marker that you can write operation, which the server then replaces with the actual timestamp when it writes the data to the database.

I'm not sure what `Date.now().valueOf()` is meant to do. Aren't you simply looking for `Date.now()`, which gives you the current timestamp?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try that before but it worked. Thank you!!